# Windows poll or select on Named pipe

Tags: pipe, named-pipes, winapi, windows

Can I use select and poll on the Named pipe handle in windows? It will be great if an example can be given. (I am very new to windows programming)

In case one of process goes down and I am polling on other end, will I get any error message on the other process that the process is down?

Comment: do you peek at the data on the pipe .

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately not.  Windows promotes two different patterns via overlapped I/O and I/O completion ports for asynchronous communication.

Briefly, overlapped I/O is briefly receiving a callback when an I/O operation completes.  IOCP is receiving an event on a *port* when an I/O operation completes and allows applications to scale up handling of many sockets simultaneously.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iocp

Worst case is you could bolt an IOCP thread onto named pipes and generate an event through a `socketpair` for handling in `select` or `WSAPoll`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a non-blocking read on the pipe, closure of the other end of the pipe (by process failure) will cause that read to return, with an error.

If you're doing a blocking read, the read will fail, as the pipe has been disconnected.